# C++, Value changes after inserting it in another varible

Tags: c++

I don't know why I have this weird problem. I have a string lets say contain the value 'a1a2'

the problem is if I try to save the second letter(1) it doesn't work, it prints me another number..
Heres my code:

```
cout << "msg is " << msg[1] << endl; // msg[1] has the value: 1
int cX = (int)(msg[0] - 'a'); // works good
int cY = (int)msg[1]; // I get different value than 1 for some reason ..
int tX = (int)(msg[2] - 'a'); // works good
int tY = msg[3]; // same problem
cout << "\ncY is " << cY << endl; // prints me other number
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is `msg` were did you initialize it?

Comment: Note that '1' is different from 1

Comment: please show how msg is declared and initialized

Comment: From what I could understand , and I am not very sure , msg is a char array , if it is outputting 1 then it is char 1 not numerical 1 , to show 1 you could subtract '0' from it ,

Comment: @Z.Zadon, we need to know how you used the msg[] !!

Comment: https://tio.run/##fVC9UoQwGOzzFDtYHBR3J@doAXi9b6CjV0QIuYyQMHxBC8dnxy9h0LOxymbZn7D1MGzrTlo9Xxlbd1OjUBlHflSyP4pfjhlj9VGIifgE@aYoajf58pJQtulKIYz16KWxSDN8ivhlsaMnjXskMpeHpJyDH1WFJNCGkIQL4@f8FFBMw36/UmdJ8GeFd9lNqkAee@pHDkwZZWmQXZ@wxUZusmj8cOMbQTvXLNqnVbskRs0DtPJoTNuqUbEopnOPtMjRuhHkegWeg5zFbheD/N/Sw3@lPpQG1c3SR5LjhtG9dqoXPwu8WH7cOgHDy98feDpPYNvt3fw1fwM

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd yup, problem was the I sent a msg(string) to a function that's why the second letter(2) is not int but '2' thanks

Comment: than how did u get 56 for cY ?? I got 49 !!

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd cuz I did not did the same string as I posted haha sorry I changed the question :) you right tho if I use a1a2 I get 49

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: I would guess he remembered the output he got, but not the input that produced it. So, he offered hypothetical input, and wrote the value he remembered getting.

Comment: Ok :) Got it !!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, appreciate it

Comment: BTW, your question would have been better if you had produced a minimal example and showed your output.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, will remember it for my next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msg[1]` is *not* the integer `1`. It's the character `'1'`. When you typecast this to an integer, as you have done in your `cY` line, you get its underlying representation, which is likely (but not necessarily) the ASCII code 49. If you want to convert a digit to an integer, you use the same trick you already used for letters.

```
int cY = (int)(msg[1] - '0');
```

Comment: Thanks!, that was the problem :)

Comment: @Z.Zadon Check the answer than ;)